# Composerで古くなったパッケージをチェックする方法

Tags: php, composer

composerでインストールしたパッケージで、既に古くなっているものをチェックする方法はあるでしょうか？

node.jsだと`npm outdated`、rubyだと、`bundle outdated`にあたる物は無いでしょうか？

Comment: `composer outdated` を追加してくれって要望は出ているようですね https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/3771

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update`に`--dry-run`オプションを指定すると、実際のupdateを行わずに、update処理をシュミレーションすることができます。結果的に、古くなったパッケージの情報を取得することが出来ます。

> $ composer update --dry-run

Answer (score 1):

composerのコマンドでという回答ではありませんが、composer.lockファイルから依存パッケージを調べて、それを登録しておくと古くなったものなどを通知してくれるサービスがあります。

https://www.versioneye.com/

トライアルアカウントでもプライベートリポジトリ1つまでは無料で使えるようです。